# Identify source of increased PostgreSQL shared memory

Tags: postgresql, shared-memory

After upgrading from PostgreSQL 9.6 to 10 and also updating the overlying application (Trend Micro Deep Security), we see an increase in the overall shared memory utilization by more than 300%.

Currently the shared memory is around 3GB, which aligns with the `shared_buffer` parameter, set to 3072MB. Using ps, top and pmap I was able to tell that almost the entire shared memory is used by postgres-related processes.

However, I would like to know what's the actual cause of that increase. Is there anyway to identify the real root cause?

Comment: Are you aware that `ps` will show shared memory for each `postgres` process even though it's used only once?

Comment: "Currently the shared memory is around 3GB, which aligns with the shared_buffer parameter, set to 3072MB."  So then the "issue" is that shared memory usage was anomalously small before the upgrade?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: yup, I was following https://www.depesz.com/2012/06/09/how-much-ram-is-postgresql-using/

Comment: @jjanes I guess that's a matter of perspective :) Independent of whether one regards the previous or the current state as nominal, I am still interested to know what caused the spike in memory utilization.

Comment: That's impossible to answer without examining your system. At any rate, it is normally considered a goid thing if a database uses the resources it has at its disposal.

Comment: You allowed Postgres to use 3GB and it uses them. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but was shared_buffers set to 1GB in your postgres 9.6?

Comment: Did you add a connection pooler, or change your monitoring?  A given process is only "charged" with whatever amount of shared memory it actually touched.  A short-lived process might never touch very much of it, while a long lived process, like one from a connection pool, or the bgwriter, or the checkpointer might touch large amounts of it.